# disable jQuery's preventDefault for children

Tags: jquery

I have a menu ul (depth 2) . I want the parent links to be unclickable so I fixed this:

```
$('li.parent a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This also disabled clicks for the children, and I Cant seem to find the opposite function for preventDefault, like so:

```
$('li.parent a li a').click(function(e) {
    e.goAndEnjoyYourDefaultBehaviourYoungPadawan();
});
```

Does that exist, or is there another best practice?

Note: I cant edit the menu, or add id's to the `<a>`'s or sommit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) rather than the [descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$('li.parent > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```